# Wildfly JMS Configuration Failure

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly

I have a problem on JMS configuration of wildfly. Application runs on standalone-full profile. I am monitoring **javax.security.sasl.SaslException**, so I guess that it is about configuration of **standalone-full.xml**. Also, I have many session beans on project, but they are working without any problem. You can view related files below.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">
<management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="IkarusLMRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <jaas name="IkarusLM"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                        <user name="sevan.nerse"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                     <append value="true"/>
                </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
            <job-repository>
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool>
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/IkarusDS" pool-name="IkarusDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@00.000.0.000:0000:ikatest</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>XXX</user-name>
                        <password>XXX</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="500000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="org.jboss.logging" slot="main"/>
                <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" slot="main"/>
                <module name="com.oracle.jdbc" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules>
            <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/IkarusDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra.rar}"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
            <default-security-domain value="IkarusLM"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.3">
            <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
                <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
            </orb>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="java:jboss/datasources/IkarusDS" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
            <hornetq-server>
                <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>

                <connectors>
                    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                        <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                    </http-connector>
                    <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                        <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    </http-connector>
                    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
                    <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    </http-acceptor>
                    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </acceptors>

                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="sys guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="sys guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="sys guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="sys guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                        <transaction mode="xa"/>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </pooled-connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>

                <jms-destinations>
                    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="Flight_Queue">
                        <entry name="java:/queue/Flight_Queue"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/Flight_Queue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="demoQueue">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/demoQueue"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/demoQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                </jms-destinations>
            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
            <endpoint worker="default"/>
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="IkarusLMRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="IkarusLM" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/IkarusDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD AS PASSWORD FROM MAINUSERS WHERE PASSIVE=0 AND USERNAME=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT R.ROLENAME, 'Roles' FROM MAINUSERS U JOIN MAINUSERROLEGROUPS URG ON U.ID=URG.USERID JOIN MAINROLEGROUPS RG ON URG.ROLEGROUPID=RG.ID JOIN MAINROLEGROUPDETS RGD ON RG.ID=RGD.ROLEGROUPID JOIN MAINROLES R ON RGD.ROLEID=R.ID WHERE U.USERNAME=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class JMSHelper
{
    protected InitialContext ic = null;
    protected ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    protected Queue queue = null;
    protected Connection connection = null;
    protected String integrationHost = null;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JMSHelper.class);

    public JMSHelper()
    {
        this("127.0.0.1");
    }

    public JMSHelper(String integrationHost)
    {
        this.integrationHost = integrationHost;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String destination, Serializable messageObject) throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        sendMessage(destination, messageObject, 0);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String destination, Serializable messageObject, int status) throws NamingException,
            JMSException
    {
        try
        {
            InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
            queue = (Queue) ic.lookup(destination);
            logger.info("destination: " + destination);
            logger.info("station: " + status);

            Session session = createSession();

            MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(queue);

            ObjectMessage messageImp = session.createObjectMessage(messageObject);
            messageImp.setJMSExpiration(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000);
            messageImp.setIntProperty("status", status);

            sender.send(messageImp);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            logger.info("exception while sending message to : " + destination);
            logger.error(exc.toString());
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    private Session createSession() throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        return connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    private InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException
    {
        if (ic == null)
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            properties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://" + integrationHost + ":8080");
            properties.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "sevan.nerse");
            properties.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "XXX");
            properties.put(InitialContext.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            properties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
            properties.put("org.jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

            return (ic = new InitialContext(properties));
        }
        else
            return ic;
    }

}
```

---

```
   15:28:36,575 WARN  [org.xnio.option.parse] (EJB default - 8) XNIO000010: Invalid option 'org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT' in property 'jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO000006: Class "org.xnio.Options" not found in ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ikarus.ear.domain_service.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    15:28:36,649 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" I/O-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
    15:32:25,800 INFO  [com.celebi.ikarus.structure.JMSHelper] (EJB default - 8) exception while sending message to : jms/queue/Flight_Queue
    15:32:25,801 ERROR [com.celebi.ikarus.structure.JMSHelper] (EJB default - 8) javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080 (Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:)] [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:]
    15:32:25,801 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 8) javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080 (Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:)] [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the user ? With the add-user.sh/bat ?

```
properties.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "sevan.nerse");
properties.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "XXX");
```

Comment: yes, it is an application user, and it has access rights to ejb's. Also, i prefered to use database server login module, and sevan.nerse is added to user table. Session beans are working without any problem but message driven beans have problems.